# What could “Du Kaschper, i Kaschper” mean?

Tags: meaning, regional

I heard somebody say “Du Kaschper” recently. What does it mean?

I think it could be some sort of German slang.

Comment: Kaspar as a noun is a children's theater figure. As a verb, (rum)kaspern means to make jokes and not pay attention to the teacher. In a southern dialect it's pronounced "kaschper(l)n". That said, without context I have no idea if this is the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: Make it an answer, @Robert.

Comment: Please explain why your sentence mixes German and English!

Comment: It would be interesting to know what behaviour of yours made your correspondent say this.

Answer (score 8):

The word is actually written *Kasper* and often also pronounced *Kasper* — only the western part of the Bavarian dialect continuum and the Alemannic dialect speakers would pronounce it *Kaschper* due to the standard sound change of /s/ turning to /ʃ/ when preceeding /t/ or /p/. This sound change has been realised for initial /s/ only in standard German but southern dialects have adopted this change in various other positions, too.

The word has been used for many funny figures in children’s books and plays, most prominently for the titular *Kasper* (northern), *Kasperle* (Swabian) or *Kasperl* (Bavarian) of the [*Kasperltheater*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasperle) — corresponding approximately to Mr. Punch in Punch and Judy shows. Another very well known figure in Germany is Otfried Preußler’s children’s book [*der Räuber Hotzenplotz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Robber_Hotzenplotz), which features *Kasperl* and *Seppel* as the two heroic main characters; Kasperl being the more playful just-do-it type frequently causing comic relief while Seppel is more thoughtful and anxious.

Etymologically, it derived from one of the three wise men, who were turned into kings and given names sometime in the middle ages. One of these three was termed Caspar and turned into an African. According to the [etymological dictionary of German](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kaspern):

> *Kasper* ist eine Nebenform von *Kaspar* (mlat. *Casparus*), dem legendären Namen eines der Heiligen Drei Könige aus dem Morgenland, der in den mittelalterlichen Dreikönigsspielen als Mohr dargestellt wird und (etwa seit dem 15. Jh.) die Gestalt einer lustigen Person annimmt. Ende des 18. Jhs. tritt er in Wien als komische Bühnenfigur an die Stelle des Hanswurst.

From these figures, colloquially and somewhat regionally the term *Kasper(l(e))* has been derived as a derogative way of saying ‘you clown’. Depending on the speaker’s intention it can be anything from joking-affectionate to an outright insult.